TypeError: draw_task() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
not sure why I am getting the error: TypeError: draw_task() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
Will appreciate any help in solving this.
import pygame
pygame.init()

#Colour Library
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
purple = (127, 0, 255)
orange = (255, 165, 0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([300, 450])
pygame.display.set_caption("Not Adventure Capitalist")
background = black
framerate = 60
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 16)
timer = pygame.time.Clock()

def draw_task():
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, (30, y_coord), 20, 5)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, [70, y_coord - 15, 200, 30])
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [75, y_coord - 10, 190, 20])


running = True
while running:
    timer.tick(framerate)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill(background)
    draw_task(green, 50)
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()


Should have given me a pygame background rectangle with a green circle and rectangle.

You get this error because you pass two arguments draw_task(green, 50) to a function expecting no arguments def draw_task():.

You may have wanted to add parameters to the definition of your function: def draw_task(color, y_coord):
